# Debian+KDE Launcher for Python Virtualenv

Tags: python, debian, virtualenv, kde-plasma

I'm trying -without success- to create a launcher in Debian with a KDE desktop (it would be a .desktop file) to launch konsole with the python virtual enviroment activated, so far this is what I have:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Network;
Comment[en_US]=Nombre
Comment=Nombre
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=konsole --noclose -e '/home/user/PyProjects/project/.venv/bin/activate'
GenericName[en_US]=Consultas
GenericName=Consultas
Icon=/ruta/al/icono
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=Consultas
Name=Consultas
Path=/home/user/PyProjects/project/
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Consultas
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-GNOME-FullName=Consultas
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=false
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
X-MultipleArgs=false
```

I'm on Debian 11 w/KDE 5.20.5, Python 3.9.2, and the script has execution permissions (577).
What I'm I missing?
Thanks in advance

PS: I also tried the Exec line with:

```
Exec=konsole --noclose -e source '/home/user/PyProjects/project/.venv/bin/activate'
Exec=konsole --noclose -e 'source /home/user/PyProjects/project/.venv/bin/activate'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of a launcher for a terminal with virtual env enabled.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment[it_IT]=
Comment=
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'source /home/gallochri/venv/bin/activate && /bin/bash'
GenericName[it_IT]=
GenericName=
Icon=system-run
MimeType=
Name[it_IT]=My venv
Name=My venv
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=\s--noclose
Type=Application
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

Comment: The `[it_IT]` localization strings are probably not useful in other locales.